# XAMPP-VM download

Tags: macos, xampp-vm

After testing my files on XAMP for MacOS (7.1.33-0) I was looking to download Wordpress or other CMS etc to test also. The Apache website suggests that the MacOS Bitnami add-ons have been deprecated and advises to download XAMPP-VM and utilise the Linux add-ons. Searching for XAMPP-VM download leads back to the Apache website XAMPP download page but I do not see the XAMPP-VM dmg to download anywhere only MacOS dmg which does not look the same file/package. Searching forums on Apache does not produce a clear result.
Does anyone know of a direct link to the file download location or can clarify the issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of a response here on SO so I posted the same question on the Apache Friends forum. Two members there strongly suggested the XAMPP-VM for Mac was highly problematic which could explain the OP. In the meantime having done further reading the general narrative appears to be that MAMP is the better developmental testing environment for Mac (able to download Bitnami add-ons) so it looks like for that purpose I will be switching at this juncture in time. Hope it helps.